# Facebook send notification from php

Tags: php, facebook, api, notifications, facebook-php-sdk

I would like to make a website with facebook notifications. I tried to send a notification to an account.
Here is my code:

```
require 'Facebook/autoload.php';

    $facebook = new Facebook\Facebook(array(
      'appId'  => FB_APP_ID,
      'secret' => FB_APP_SECRET,
    ));


    $post = $facebook->api('/' . $user['uid'] . '/notifications/', 'POST/v2.2/',  array(
      'access_token' => FB_APP_ID.'|'.FB_APP_SECRET,
      'href' => "http://mydomainlink.com",  //this does link to the app's root, don't think this actually works, seems to link to the app's canvas page
      'template' => 'Max 180 characters',
      'ref' => 'Notification sent '.date("Y-m-d G:i:s") //this is for Facebook's insight
    ));
```

And the result:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException' with message 'Required "app_id" key not supplied in config and could not find fallback environment variable "FACEBOOK_APP_ID"' in /var/www/webpages/Facebook/Facebook.php:133 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/webpages/fbnotify.php(14): Facebook\Facebook->__construct(Array) #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/webpages/Facebook/Facebook.php on line 133

The users login to the website with facebook, so I can get the userid from there.

Comment: The error is right there! "Required "app_id" key not supplied"

Comment: I made a project, and generate id and password.. The login work successfully.. What do you advice?

Comment: The `Facebook\Facebook` class does not have a method named `api`. Looks like this is using old code written for the PHP SDK v4. Go check the documentation to see what methods are available in v5.